# Undefined method when using static import

Tags: java, import, static, undefined

I'm reading 'Thinking in Java, 4th edition' and can't get past this exercise:

> Create two packages: debug and debugoff, containing an identical class
>   with a debug( ) method. The first version displays its String argument
>   to the console, the second does nothing. Use a static import line to
>   import the class into a test program, and demonstrate the conditional
>   compilation effect.

There is obviously something I'm missing because when I try this:

```
// C:\Users\user\Documents\EclipseProjects\DebugOnOff\bin\debugonoff\debugon
package debugonoff.debugon;
public class Test {
    public static void debug(String str) {}
}

// C:\Users\user\Documents\EclipseProjects\DebugOnOff\bin\debugonoff\debug
package debugonoff.debug;
public class Test {
    public static void debug(String str) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}

// C:\Users\user\Documents\EclipseProjects\DebugOnOff\bin
import static debugonoff.debug.Test.*;
public class TestProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        debug("Hi there!");
    }
}
```

this error message occurs:

> The method debug(String) is undefined for the type TestProgram

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the static import as you specified to import the methods

1. You can use the static import to access or import the members(Objects)

For Ex: System.out.println(""); -> can be replaced by
        out.println(""); if you made a static import of java.lang.System.*;

2. In any case it is not advisable to use the static imports much because it will reduce the code readability and maintainability.
3. static methods can only be accessed as minimal as Class.methodName()
   or as usual as new class().methodName()

**addComment** if you are unclear

Answer (score 0):

This code should work. At least it does for me.

Which compiler, Java version, IDE and operating system do you use?

Please note that the other 2 comments are not correct reffering to the [oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html). Static imports can be done for methods. The example in the documentation is

`import static java.lang.Math.*;
 double r = cos(PI * theta);`

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your project setup?

I copied your code into a project of mine and it works.

And from the paths that you've shown it seems that your code lives in the `bin` directory - that is where eclipse normally places the compiled `.class` files. Your source files should live in the `src` directory.